# Blender button with the bool property doesn't update at first click. Any way to fix this?

Tags: python, blender, add-on

I'm using a simple code (Blender 3.0) to add a modifier to a selected object by pressing a button on a panel. It works fine, but when I **Apply** this mod and **select another object**, my Button reacts only from the second click. It looks like the Button didn't update itself.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel, AddonPreferences
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, PointerProperty
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

class OBJECT_PT_OCD_panel(Panel):
    bl_label = 'Super remesher'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Remesher_test'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        obj = context.active_object
                    
        row = self.layout.column()
        row.scale_y = 2.0
            
        is_depressed = True
        rem_btn = "Remesh"
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.name == "My_Remesh":
                    rem_btn = "Cancel"
                    is_depressed = False
             
        row.operator("object.remesh", text = rem_btn, depress = is_depressed)
        col = self.layout.column()
        col.operator("object.apply_all_mods", text = "Apply")

#---Defining if Remesh ON
def mod_on(context):
    
        bpy.context.object.modifiers.new("My_Remesh", type='REMESH')
        return {'FINISHED'}

#---Defining if Remesh OFF
def mod_off(context):
        
        obj = context.active_object
        for mod in obj.modifiers:
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier= "My_Remesh")

        return {'FINISHED'}

#---Defining if Apply
def mod_apply(context):
    
    active_obj = context.view_layer.objects.active
    #---Apply all mods
    for mod in active_obj.modifiers:
        #bpy.ops.object.apply_all_modifiers()
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier= "My_Remesh")
```

1st operator with bool property:

```
class OBJECTON_OT_remesh(Operator):
    bl_label = "modremesher"
    bl_idname = "object.remesh"
    bl_description = "remesh an object"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bpy.context.object.select_get() and bpy.context.object.type == 'MESH' and bpy.context.object.mode == 'OBJECT'
    
    my_bool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle Option", default=True)


    def execute(self, context):
        
        self.my_bool = not self.my_bool
        if self.my_bool :
            mod_on(context)
        else:
            mod_off(context)
         
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

2nd operator with apply to mod:

```
         
class OBJECT_OT_apply(Operator):
    bl_label = "Apply all"
    bl_idname = "object.apply_all_mods"
    bl_description = "Apply remesh"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"        

    #---Test
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        objs = context.selected_objects
        for modifier in obj.modifiers:
            if modifier.type == "REMESH": 
                return True
            else:
                pass
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def execute(self, context):
        mod_apply(context)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

registering Classes

```
#---Classes register list
classes = [
    OBJECTON_OT_remesh,
    OBJECT_PT_OCD_panel,
    OBJECT_OT_apply,
]

def register():
    for cl in classes:
       register_class(cl)
       
def unregister():
    for cl in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cl)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong because `my_bool: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Toggle Option", default=True)` is a type annotation in python 3.6+. I was using an old version of blender (2.79) which uses python 3.5.3 and that's why it was a syntax error. I've deleted my answer.